# Is There Any Way to Use Import_CSS to Add Styles to the Toolbar StyleSelect Option in TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using import_css to load CSS styles, which are then visible on the menubar under Format.

```
importcss_append: true,
importcss_file_filter: tinymce_content_css_location,
importcss_groups: [ 
  {title: 'SiteCommander Images', filter: /(.image-)/ },
  {title: 'SiteCommander Styles'}
],
menu : {
  ...
  format: { title: 'Format', items: '... | formats' },
  ...
},
```

Result:

[image]

However, these same styles do not appear by default on the toolbar item **styleselect**.

[image]

Is there any way to make styleselect match formats?

Answer (score 0):

The formats toolbar button (`styleselect` in your configuration) is controlled by the `style_formats` configuration option and not external CSS.  For example:

```
style_formats: [
    {title: 'Red text', inline: 'span', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
    {title: 'Red header', block: 'h1', styles: {color: '#ff0000'}},
    {title: 'Example 1', inline: 'span', classes: 'example1'},
    {title: 'Example 2', inline: 'span', classes: 'example2'},
    {title: 'Table row 1', selector: 'tr', classes: 'tablerow1'},
    {title: 'LI List Class', selector: 'li', classes: 'liclass'},
    {title: 'UL List Class', selector: 'ul', classes: 'listclass'},
    {title: 'Image Float Right', selector: 'img', styles: {float: 'right'}}
],
```

Comment: Thank you, Michael. You probably suspect that I know about this. However, what I'm asking is how to make the Formats option work the same on both the menu and the toolbar. In my case, these formats differ from site to site, so having them load automatically is key.

Comment: They don't ... they are different plugins performing different tasks.  You could certainly create your own plugin to create a toolbar option like the `styleselect` and have it show whatever styles you like pulled from wherever you like.

Comment: Sheesh. I really don't want to become a plugin expert (JS is not one of my strong points). Maybe it's necessary.